# IIS url rewrite - css and js incorrectly being rewritten

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

Having an issue with my urlrewrites - anytime I point to a page that is to be rewritten it fails to display because it is also applying the rule to the css & js files that are referenced within my webpage.

To try and remedy this I put in a fully qualified path to the css and js - this renders fine on any page where the rewrite isnt applied yet when i try to access a rewritten page the browser hangs.

Has anyone encountered something similar and if so have you a solution? Appreciate any help. Tried looking on the site at similar issues but none have helped so far.

```
<rewrite>
<outboundRules>
<rule name="OutboundRewriteUserFriendlyURL1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1" stopProcessing="true">
<match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^(.*/)myapplicationname/Index\.html\?team=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
<action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}team/{R:2}/" />
</rule>
<preConditions>
<preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
<add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
</preCondition>
</preConditions>
</outboundRules>
<rules>
<rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^myapplicationname/Index\.html$" />
<conditions>
<add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
<add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^([^=&amp;]+)=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}/{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
<rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
<conditions>
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="Index.html?{R:1}={R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

within my webpage:

```
<script src="/myapplicationname/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript">    </script>
<link href="/myapplicationname/Styles/MainStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

it is applying the rewrite to these and trying to find /myapplicationname/Team/Styles/MainStyle.css and similar with the JS file.

Answer (score 5):

Try to find out which rule is causing the problem by removing them one by one.  Now add a condition to that rule:

```
    <rule name="Some rule">
      ...
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
          <add input="{URL}" pattern="^.*\.(ashx|axd|css|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|js|flv|f4v)$" negate="true" /> 
      </conditions>
    </rule>
```

This will avoid running the rule on files ending with .js, .css, etc.